# Django - managing multiple pages with multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using Django for developing a website and I want to allow my staff to be able to add/edit/delete pages with multiple text fields. I am planning to use Django's admin framework for this as the staff is a non-technical one.But I have no clue on how to go about doing this so that people can login and edit the contents on these pages whenever they want. 
    Also, my site will be receiving around 1500 hits per day. I don't want to embed these pages in static templates (so that I can allow my staff to edit it). Will loading this data at runtime slow down my site. I am using a Servint VPS server.

Thanks
niting

Comment: Read the [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/), mission accomplished att Chapter 6.

Comment: 1500 hits a day? Performance won't be a concern with such a tiny load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), replacing the concept of Polls with Pages, and Choices with Content blocks and you'll be most of the way there (Django's built in Admin will allow you to edit these models).

For a more advanced CMS based on Django take a look at either [Django CMS](http://www.django-cms.org/) or [FeinCMS](http://www.feinheit.ch/labs/feincms-django-cms/).